# How to upload a file on the frontend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, multer, form-data

i got the following issue. I'm developing an application whit node.js on the backend and React on the frontend where the user can upload files. My code on the backend works fine; when i use postman the file uploads successfully without error and insert on my database. Now when I want to do the code on the frontend I got the following error:

[error backend node.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snuq4.png)

it says that cannot read the filename, my code on react is the next:

`

```
const UploadNomina = () => {

  let formData = new FormData()

  const uploadFiles = e => {
    console.log(e.target.files);
    if (e.target && e.target.files[0]) {
      formData.append('cfdi', e.target.files[0])
    }
  }

  const insertFiles = async () => {

    try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

      if (!token) return
     
      const config = {
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
      }

      const upLoadFile = await clienteAxios.post('/cfdi-nomina', formData, config)
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.upload}>
      <div className={styles.upload_div}>
        <div className={styles.upload_title}>
          <h1>Carga tu archivo aquí</h1>
          <p className={styles.drop_text}>Si carga correctamente tu cfdi podrás ir al modulo de nómina y verlo desde allí</p>
          <input type="file" name="files" onChange={uploadFiles}/>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => insertFiles()}
          >Insertar Archivos</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      {msg && <Alerta alerta={alerta} />}
    </div>
  )
}

export default UploadNomina
```

`

On the backend here is my line of code where the app crash:

`

```
const uploadNomina = async (req, res, next) => {

    let jsonCfdi = null;
    
    upload(req, res, async(error) => {

        try {

            if (!error) {
                
                jsonCfdi = await CfdiToJson.parse({ 
                    path : __dirname+`/../uploads/${req.file.filename}`
                });
```

`

I've tried unsuccessfully and I always get the same error. I got doubts because when I do it whit postman it runs ok so I don't understand if my problem is whether on the backend or in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

try using it like this. it may be possible that format is not same in image[0] and you are getting name in backend.

```
 data.append('cfdi', {
        uri: e.target.files[0].uri,
        name: 'image.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
      })
```

and change the content type in headers to

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```